# Getting actual type from generic type

Tags: c#, generics

I'm wondering if this is possible.  I have a generic class that looks like so:

```
public class SomeClass<T> : SomeInterface
{
    public SomeClass()
    {
      var someVariable = new OtherClass("string_parameter");
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is use that generic parameter in my `OtherClass` constructor, sort of like `OtherClass(T.GetType().ToString())` but am having no luck.  Is what I'm after possible, or can I not get at the `T` parameter in that fashion?

Comment: 1. Why do you want to do this? 2. Use `typeof(T).Name` to do this.

Comment: To answer 1. `OtherClass` is a logging component of ours and we want to log the class that called it.  Regarding #2, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `typeof(T).Name`

Comment: I knew I was circling it.  Thanks!